# UIImageを継承したクラスを作成したい

Tags: swift

理想は以下のように実装したいのです。

```
enum MyImageType:String{
     case OnButton  = "on_btn.png"
     case OffButton = "off_btn.png"    
}

class MyImage: UIImage {

    init?(typed type:MyImageType){
        super.init(named:type.rawValue) //<-ここでエラーがでます。
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required convenience init(imageLiteral name: String) {
        fatalError("init(imageLiteral:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

//使用する際
let myImg = MyImage(typed:.OnButton)
```

しかし、
Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIImage'
というエラーが出てしまいます。

指定イニシャライザを呼べということなのですが、

```
class MyImage: UIImage {

    init?(typed type:MyImageType){
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required convenience init(imageLiteral name: String) {
        fatalError("init(imageLiteral:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

このように書き直すと、エラーはでないのですが、自分のやりたいことが実現できません。
何か方法はありませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やりたいことは`MyImageType`を引数に取れるイニシャライザを追加したい、ということだと思いますので、おそらくサブクラス化するより、エクステンションを使ってカスタムイニシャライザを追加する方が簡単だと思います。

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(typed: MyImageType) {
        self.init(named: typed.rawValue)
    }
}
```

^ 上記のようなエクステンションを書くと、

```
let myImg = UIImage(typed: .OnButton)
```

^ のように使用することができます。

どうしても継承を使いたいという場合は下記のようにする感じでしょうか。
イニシャライザのうち`UIImage(named:)`は継承されない（おそらくファクトリメソッドをコンバートしたイニシャライザのため）ので内部で`UIImage(named:)`を使って生成したインスタンスでさらに自分自身を初期化するという、少しトリッキーな実装になっています。

```
class MyImage: UIImage {
    convenience init?(typed: MyImageType) {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: typed.rawValue), let CGImage = image.CGImage else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(CGImage: CGImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。目的がもう一つあるのですが、MyImageのような別の名前空間を用いたい場合はどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: もう一つの目的とは具体的にどのようなものでしょうか？単にMyImageを使ってUIImageを返したいのであれば、MyImageクラスにUIImageを返すようなメソッドを定義すればいいのでは、と思います。

Comment: UIに使用する多くの画像を一つにまとめて管理しようと考えています。
おっしゃる通り当初はMyImageにクラスメソッドを用いて、UIImageを返すようにしていました。
let btnImg = MyImage.imageType(MyImage.OnButton)
このように使っていたのですが、このように書くくらいなら、
let btnImg = MyImage(typed:MyImage.OnButton)
と書きたいなと考えた次第です。

Comment: @kratos 継承を使った場合の方法を追記しました。UIImageを継承するのはあまりオススメしませんし、動作は確認してませんが、おそらく動くと思います。